# Split a numeric string into thousands in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have an int in php, like 5454676.
After I convert it into a string, I would like to split that into thousands, starting at the end.
So 5454676 would become

```
[ 
 0 => 5,
 1 => 454, 
 2 => 676
]
```

I've tried str_split but it splits from the left side. So 5000 becomes

```
$number = (string) 5000;
$split = str_split( $number, 3 );
// split is like [ 0 => 5, 1 => 000 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution without regexp:

```
$split = explode(";", number_format($number, 0, "", ";"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format the number in groups of 3 digits then use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the returned string using the separator used by `number_format()` to separate the groups:

```
$number = 5454676;
print_r(explode(',', number_format($number, 0)));
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 454
    [2] => 676
)
```

Comment: This would be how I would've done it too! If it isn't what you want you could always do a messy function like: `array_reverse(str_split( strrev($number), 3 ))` which does the same but is **much** more cumbersome.